# ¿Crear un bot para reproducir música de Spotify con Node es posible?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo un bot para discord en el cual reproduzco canciones de Youtube, pero estoy tratando de implementar listas de spotify y no encuentro nada.

Con la API de spotify parece que no hay nada específico para conseguir el audio de las canciones. Alguien tiene alguna idea?

(He probado a reproducir las canciones de las listas de spotify con youtube, pero entre que la API de youtube te banea la IP por peticiones, y que no siempre es la misma canción, es poco práctico)

Comment: No puedo probarlo pero fijate si funciona este bot https://top.gg/bot/585225058683977750.

Comment: La cuestión es que me gustaría poder hacerlo yo :), es por aprender.

Comment: @Kleith en la descripción del bot solo puede obtener información de spotify. La música la reproduce desde youtube. Hasta abajo lo menciona >Music only plays from youtube.

Comment: Si, he estado investigando y es de las pocas cosas que se pueden hacer. Lo malo es que la ytdl-core (para reproducir audio), tiene algun tipo de problema con el limite de peticiones, y me está bloqueando haciendo menos de 200peticiones/día. Seguiré investigando

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde he leido no hay manera de reproducir directamente la música desde un aplicativo externo.

Sin embargo, al parecer puedes controlar remotamente el cliente de spotify desde una aplicación externa https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/

Pero dice que esta en beta.